# Buscar registros para llenar automáticamente unos input

Tags: php, html5

```html
<form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="BUSCAR POR CORREO..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                  <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <!--termina el buscador-->
        <form action="regventas.php" method="post" name="f1" onsubmit="return validar(this);">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 15px";>
                <h1 class="h1">Registro Cliente</h1>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox ">
                  <div class="inputText">*Nombre Titular</div>
                  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="input" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Nombre Comercial</div>
                  <input type="text" id="nom_com" name="nom_com" class="input" required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Tengo un buscador en un registro, quiero buscar por correo para si ya existe el cliente solo llenar automaticamente sus datos personales si no existe que me arroje un mensaje de que no existe, alguna manera de como hacer la consulta?

Comment: Bienvenido, solo nos estas colocando el HTML, haría falta la consulta SQL, la estructura de la tabla, lo que has intentado al momento, los errores obtenido, etc; por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour]

Comment: Simplemente puedes hacer una petición en ajax a un archivo php que te traiga los datos, sí existen, sino que devuelva algún false. Deberías agregar lo que te dice @Aprendiz para poderte ayudar.